# Android app gets terminated when comes from background

Tags: android, asynchronous, terminate

My Android app is terminated if it comes from background with below error. Any help...

```
12-09 10:43:36.675: W/dalvikvm(3709): Invalid indirect reference 0x41873b40 in decodeIndirectRef
12-09 10:43:36.675: E/dalvikvm(3709): VM aborting
12-09 10:43:36.675: A/libc(3709): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 3735 (AsyncTask #1)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this> what your doing exactly?

Comment: seems more like an out of memory error?

Comment: The app is for displaying data that is stored in application session.
The app is running fine, but the error comes when it comes from background after opening other applications. Also I am not able to get more stacktrace.